# Struct won't coerce to implemented dyn Trait type in function return

Tags: rust, traits, coercion

I have the following Rust code

```rust
use std::{
    cell::{Ref, RefCell},
    rc::Rc,
};

trait TraitA {
    fn data(&self) -> Ref<Vec<Rc<dyn TraitB>>>;
}

struct A {
    data: RefCell<Vec<Rc<B>>>,
}

impl TraitA for A {
    fn data(&self) -> Ref<Vec<Rc<dyn TraitB>>> {
        self.data.borrow()
    }
}

trait TraitB {}

struct B {}

impl TraitB for B {}
```

However I get the following error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:16:9
   |
15 |     fn data(&self) -> Ref<Vec<Rc<dyn TraitB>>> {
   |                       ------------------------ expected `Ref<'_, Vec<Rc<(dyn TraitB + 'static)>>>` because of return type
16 |         self.data.borrow()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn TraitB`, found struct `B`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Ref<'_, Vec<Rc<(dyn TraitB + 'static)>>>`
              found struct `Ref<'_, Vec<Rc<B>>>`
```

I have tried setting the `data` field in `A` to have type `RefCell<Vec<Rc<dyn TraitB>>>`. That will work.

However in my implementation I want to have the field contain the type `B` as I want the Vec to store *only* type `B`, not any implementation of `TraitB`.

My understanding is that Rust should be able to coerce the `B` type as required as long as it implements the trait `TraitB`, which in the example above, `B` does indeed implement `TraitB`.

For example, in the following snippet, `Rc<dyn TraitB>` is successfully coerced to `Rc<B>` no problem.

```rust
struct C {
    weak_ref: Weak<B>,
}

impl C {
    fn upgrade_weak_ref(&self) -> Rc<dyn TraitB> {
        self.weak_ref.upgrade().unwrap()
    }
}
```

So my question is, why is the coercion not working in the first example above. Is it because it's contained in a `Ref`? Is there a workaround or some way to make it work without changing the type of the `data` field in struct `A`?

Comment: Possible workaround: use an associated type ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d7c4252749d4c44676f55266d4e9f8f5)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rc<dyn TraitB>` is twice the size of `Rc<B>` (two usizes versus one). Therefore, there *cannot* be a way to coerce a `Vec<Rc<B>>` to `Vec<Rc<dyn TraitB>>` without rebuilding the vector.

You can store `Vec<Rc<dyn TraitB>>`, but have only methods that push `B`s and therefore protect against misuse.